# How to keep bluetooth audio device to connect in high power mode?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

With some of the bluetooth 3.0 devices, the device will go into idle mode if there is no audio for a while (a couple of seconds maybe), and when the audio is restored, the device will have a obvious delay and pop sound (like 2 seconds or so). This is very annoying. I understand bluetooth devices will go into the idle mode to save power, but in my case I want it to run in high power mode all the time. Is it possible to force macOS to keep bluetooth devices alerted for audio bits all the time?